# Why the normalization constant of betweenness centrality is $(N-1)(N-2)/2$?

Tags: graph-theory

As stated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality), the betweenness centrality of a node $v$ is given by the expression:
$$g(v)=\sum _{{s\neq v\neq t}}{\frac  {\sigma _{{st}}(v)}{\sigma _{{st}}}}$$
where $\sigma_{st}$ is the total number of shortest paths from node s to node t and $\sigma_{st}(v)$ is the number of those paths that pass through v.

The calculation may be rescaled by $(N-1)(N-2)/2$ for undirected graphs, where $N$ is the number of nodes. I can't explain why this quantity.

Comment: The first article is: Linton C. Freeman (1977). A Set of Measures of Centrality Based on Betweenness. Sociometry, 40(1), 35–41.

Comment: The second article is: Piraveenan, Mahendra; Prokopenko, Mikhail; Hossain, Liaquat; Holme, Petter (2013). Percolation Centrality: Quantifying Graph-Theoretic Impact of Nodes during Percolation in Networks. PLoS ONE, 8(1), e53095–.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fraction $\frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}$ is certainly between $0$ and $1$; in some cases, all paths between $s$ and $t$ pass through $v$, and then it is equal to $1$.

In an $N$-vertex graph, there are $\binom{N-1}{2} = \frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{2}$ ways to choose a pair $\{s,t\}$ where $s$, $t$, and $v$ are all distinct. Therefore, when we define $g(v)$ to be the sum of $\frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}$ over all such pairs $\{s,t\}$, the possible values of $g(v)$ range from $0$ to $\binom{N-1}{2}$. Both extremes are possible:

- When $v$ has degree $1$, there are no paths that pass through $v$ but do not start or end there: $\sigma_{st}(v) = 0$ for all pairs $\{s,t\}$ in the sum. Therefore $g(v) = 0$ as well.
- Suppose the graph only has $N-1$ edges: the edges from $v$ to every other vertex. Then $\sigma_{st}(v) = \sigma_{st} = 1$ for every pair $\{s,t\}$ in the sum, and we get $g(v) = \binom{N-1}{2}$.

We divide by $\binom{N-1}{2}$ to obtain a measure of betweenness centrality that ranges between $0$ and $1$.

One reason we might want to do this is if we want to compare how central two vertices are in *different* graphs. If we did not normalize, then we'd generally expect all (or almost all) vertices in a large graph to be "more central" than the vertices in a small graph, which is a bit silly.

---

Wikipedia does not mention this, but the sum defining $g(v)$ should also be different for directed graphs - not just the normalization constant. In undirected graphs, $\sigma_{st} = \sigma_{ts}$, $\sigma_{st}(v) = \sigma_{ts}(v)$, and so we might as well sum over *unordered* pairs $\{s,t\}$. In directed graphs, these path counts are not necesssarily symmetric, so we should some over *ordered* pairs $(s,t)$ - though we still require that $s \ne t$. This doubles the number of terms in the sum, so then we divide by $(N-1)(N-2)$ to normalize.

We could also sum over ordered pairs $(s,t)$ for both kinds of graphs, and divide by $(N-1)(N-2)$ to normalize for both. This causes no harm for undirected graphs, we'd just have $\binom{N-1}{2}$ pairs of identical terms in the sum.

Comment: Great answer, @Misha Lavrov!